# Django complex query to fetch data from groupby and having clause

Tags: django, group-by, django-queryset, annotate

I want to execute group by clause on MyUser table having CNT.Status exactly one the raw query would be like below.

```
SELECT user_id from user_table GROUP BY user_id HAVING COUNT(status)=1
```

I tried various options using Django model API but its adding "id" too in group by clause.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems you are looking for [filtering on annotations](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/aggregation/#filtering-on-annotations):

```
qs = ( MyUser
      .objects
      .annotate(num_status=Count('status'))
      .filter(num_status__gt=1)
     )
```

Notice: I supose that status is a 1:N related model.

Comment: isn't this missing `.values('user_id')`. Just curious.

Comment: @Shubham  Yes, `.values_list( 'user_id', flat=True )` to be more precise. Thanks.