# Is it possible to accomplish a custom group and having query?

Tags: django, tastypie

I'm looking to only pull collections where all related tags exist.  This is the query that returns what I need.  Now I need to figure out a way to get this to work with tastypie.

Currently I can query like this, but It pulls all collections that have those associated tags (even if the collection only has one).  I need to pull collections that have both.

```
/collection/?tag__name__in=Tag1,Tag2
```

The query that accomplishes what I need is:

```
select * from collection
 join tag
    on tag.collection_id = tag.id
 where tag.name in ('Tag1', 'Tag2') 
 group by 
    collection.name 
 having
    COUNT(DISTINCT tag.name) = 2;
```

Would `build_filters` be the way to go for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this question and answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14827899/django-complex-query-to-fetch-data-from-groupby-and-having-clause)

You basically need to annotate/aggregate and then filter. The order is important.

Filtering after annotating creates the having clause you need